# Get Windows PC Notifications/Updates on Android Mobile

Tags: notification-bar, screen-sharing

I need a way to get all the desktop taskbar updates/notifications on my Android device.

Example: Someone pings me on my Office Communicator on PC. I need to see that as a notification on my Android Device.

Not looking for screensharing apps such as Teamviewer where I need to connect and check the screen for updates.

What I'm looking for is the exact opposite of [Desktop Notifications](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.hcilab.projects.notification).

Is there any way to do this? Third-party apps are acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sending phone notifications to desktop work because there is a simple framework for the phones, and all your app as to do is listen for that event and echo the message to the desktop.

The reverse is significantly harder because there is simply no unified notification framework yet. Every app handles notifications differently. I haven't written desktop apps for windows at that depths, but notice how most application icons on the taskbar light up when there's an event? (May not always be a valid notification). Well, my first guess is that you'd have to write a listener for that - assuming you're given that kind of access in the OS in the first place. [ [Check out this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17703201/how-to-detect-changes-to-the-windows-system-tray) ].

Once you have a listener in place, you can know **when** an app receives a notification. However, unless the app exposes a method to see what the notification is though the taskbar, it is unlikely that you can derive the contents ...

Answer (score 4):

The implementation of what you are asking is too application-specific to work well for most computer applications, thus the usual (and possibly only) solution you will find is use some screensharing app. All applications handle such notifications differently, so it would be too hard to make it work for all applications correctly.