# Get Android notifications in Windows

Tags: windows

This question doesn't seem to have been asked here before, although the exact opposite question (get Windows notifications in Android) [has been asked](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/66233/get-windows-pc-notifications-updates-on-android-mobile).

I'm thinking here of getting notifications in Windows from (pretty much) all Android apps, and not from a tiny subset of apps (e.g. messaging apps).

There used to be a way to get app notifications through Cortana, but that was [disabled in 2018](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/what-happened-to-notification-syncing-in-android/f487a105-2d0c-4048-93ba-5dea3066884e) and still has not been enabled either in Cortana or in any other product offered by Microsoft. Is there some other way to do it?

Comment: See https://community.kde.org/KDEConnect#Windows. You can build KDEConnect for Windows.

Answer (score 1):

I've had great success with Join in the past (and in fact with Tasker overall, which is superb): https://joaoapps.com/join/

And while it's a paid service, Pushbullet has also been very useful: https://www.pushbullet.com/