# View PC notifications on phone

Tags: notifications, windows

I know that this has been asked before [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/66233/get-windows-pc-notifications-updates-on-android-mobile), but I don't have sufficient reputation to post a comment here and ask if there is an update applying to Windows 10/11. I am looking a solution for the exact same question: How to view Windows notifications on my Android phone? May be there was no unified method of showing notifications on Windows at the time linked question has been asked, but as Windows 10/11 are designed with tablet mode in mind, there is a chance that Microsoft has made such a unification. I have searched Google Play for an app, found only one requiring an open browser window, which isn't what I'm looking for. Anyone having a solution for this?

Comment: Hello. As you are aware your question is a duplicate of the linked question. In a situation where you find a question which matches your problem but the answers there do not seem relevant or helpful to you, than a good approach in such a situation is to offer a bounty on that question. To offer a bounty, you would need to gain reputation points so that you can spend them for offering the bounty. Our [help] center can get you started with that. Good luck. :)